# what is the difference between include/v8-object.h with src/objects/objects.h

Tags: javascript, v8

I am learning v8's source code and I found there are many definition about Object.

1. in `include/v8-object.h`
2. in `src/objects/objects.h`
3. in `src/objects/js-objects.h`

so what is the difference and how v8 handle the creation of Javascript Object (by literal or constructor)

Comment: _"so what is the difference and how v8 handle the creation of Javascript Object (by literal or constructor)"_ - keep on reading through V8's souce to find out then. Download a repo clone and fire-up an IDE that will let you F12/Jump around the source code by following references and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the sources would answer this question. The summary is:

- `include/v8-object.h` defines `v8::Object`, which is the object class that's exposed on V8's public API. As the comment there says, it corresponds to a JavaScript object.
- `src/objects/objects.h` defines `v8::internal::Object`, which is the superclass of anything on the managed heap (both JavaScript objects and various kinds of internal representations and internal metadata are subclasses of this).
- `src/objects/js-objects.h` defines the internal representation of JavaScript objects.

> how v8 handle the creation of Javascript Object

The short answer is: it allocates them on the managed heap.

The fully detailed answer is much longer than appropriate for a SO post, and changes all the time. Read the source code if you really care.

Comment: Thanks, I am a frontend, your explanation really helps me to understand the C++ code